# Верно ли создан JS Object и правельно я понял его работу

Tags: javascript

Вот **JS Object**:

```
(function () {
    if(window.$DOM) return;
    var domObj = function (element, context) {
        return new domObj.fn.Init(context, element);
    };

    domObj.fn = domObj.prototype = {
        Init: function (context, element) {
            this.element = element;
            if(!context)
              this.context = document;
            else this.context = context;
            }
        },

        AddEvent: function (event, handler) {
            var object = this.element;
            if (!object) return;

            if (object.attachEvent)
                object.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
            else
                if (object.addEventListener)
                    object.addEventListener(event, handler, false);

            return this;
        },

        RemoveEvent: function (event, handler) {
            var object = this.element;
            if (!object) return;

            if (object.detachEvent) {
                object.detachEvent("on" + event, handler);
            }
            else
                if (object.removeEventListener) {
                    object.removeEventListener(event, handler, false);
                }
            return this;
        },
    };
    domObj.fn.Init.prototype = domObj.fn;

    window.$DOM = domObj;
})();
```

---

Здесь я его использую:

```
function click(){
    alert("click!");
}

$DOM("buttont").AddEvent("click", click);
$DOM("buttont").RemoveEvent("click", click);
```

правильно ли я понимаю что здесь будут созданны 2 объекта `domObj.prototype.Init{this.element=...; this.context=...}` а `AddEvent` и `RemoveEvent` будут вызываться из `prototype` и передовать  в качестве **this** созданный соответствующий`domObj.prototype.Init`?

Comment: `object` - лучше не использовать в качестве имени переменной

А вообще - спагетти ужасный...

Ответ на ваш вопрос - да

Comment: вооо это хорошо :)), а что именно ужасно?

Comment: ваш код можно сократить, навскидку, примерно на 40%...
****
Я бы не сказал что код ужасен, но явно слишком много воды

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ИМХО - как делать такую задачу:

```
(function () {
    if(window.$DOM) return;

    var obj = function ( element, context ) {
      this.context = context || document;

      this.element = element;
    };

    if ( document.body.addEventListener ){
      obj.prototype.listen = function ( event, handler ){
        this.element.addEventListener( event, handler, false );

        return this;
      }

      obj.prototype.unlisten = function ( event, handler ){
        this.element.removeEventListener( event, handler, false );

        return this;
      }
    }
    else if ( document.body.attachEvent ){
      obj.prototype.listen = function ( event, handler ){
        this.element.attachEvent( 'on' + event, handler );

        return this;
      }

      obj.prototype.unlisten = function ( event, handler ){
        this.element.detachEvent( 'on' + event, handler );

        return this;
      }
    }
    else throw Error( "Я не знаю как вешать обработчик в этом браузере" );

    window.$DOM = function ( el, context ){
      if ( typeof element === 'string' ) el = document.getElementById( el );

      return ( el.$dom || el.$dom = new obj( el, context ) );
    }
})();
```

И соответственно:

```
$DOM( 'buttont' ).listen( 'click', click );
$DOM( 'buttont' ).unlisten( 'click', click );
```

Что-бы `prototype` было 1 раз, можно так:

```
(function () {
    if(window.$DOM) return;

    var obj = function ( element, context ) {
          this.context = context || document;

          this.element = element;
        },
        event_flag;

    if ( document.body.addEventListener ) event_flag = true;
    else if ( document.body.attachEvent ) event_flag = false;
    else throw Error( "Я не знаю как вешать обработчик в этом браузере" );

    obj.prototype = {
      constructor: obj,
      listen: ( event_flag ? 
        function ( event, handler ){
          this.element.addEventListener( event, handler, false );
          return this;
        } :
        function ( event, handler ){
          this.element.attachEvent( 'on' + event, handler );
          return this;
        }
      ),
      unlisten: ( event_flag ?
        function ( event, handler ){
          this.element.removeEventListener( event, handler, false );
          return this;
        } :
        function ( event, handler ){
          this.element.detachEvent( 'on' + event, handler );
          return this;
        }
      )
    }

    window.$DOM = function ( el, context ){
      if ( typeof element === 'string' ) el = document.getElementById( el );
      return ( el.$dom || el.$dom = new obj( el, context ) );
    }
})();
```

Но я-бы не стал...

Comment: прикольно, но obj.prototype часто используется

Comment: И в чём проблема?

Comment: ну впринцепи нету :))